# Nothing to be done and No rule to make target

Tags: makefile, compilation

I am trying to make an object file of a subroutine. I have followed the following (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585452/makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target-how-to-solve-it, https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/10847/error-make-no-rule-to-make-target-mario-stop/10852) but couldn't fix the error. The make file that is used is:

```
ifndef PVFMM_DIR
PVFMM_DIR=./..
endif

-include $(PVFMM_DIR)/MakeVariables

ifndef CXX_PVFMM
$(error Cannot find file: MakeVariables)
endif

FC_PVMM = mpif90
FC = mpif90

FC=$(FC_PVFMM) # TODO: for now, FC must be provided by user
CC=$(CC_PVFMM) # TODO: for now, CC must be provided by user
CXX=$(CXX_PVFMM)
CXXFLAGS=$(CXXFLAGS_PVFMM)
LDLIBS=$(LDLIBS_PVFMM)

RM = rm -f
MKDIRS = mkdir -p

BINDIR = ./bin
SRCDIR = ./src
OBJDIR = ./obj
INCDIR = ./include

TARGET_BIN = \
       $(OBJDIR)/example-f.o

all : example-f.o

example-f.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
    -@$(MKDIRS) $(dir $@)
    @echo "here" $(dir $@)
    $(PVFMM_DIR)/libtool --mode=link --tag=FC mpif90 $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $^ $(LDLIBS) -c $@
```

I get the following error:

```
cd ./examples && make;
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/bidesh/Coding/FMM/pvfmm-develop/examples'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'src/%.f90', needed by 'example-f.o'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bidesh/Coding/FMM/pvfmm-develop/examples'
Makefile:1410: recipe for target 'all-examples' failed
make: *** [all-examples] Error 2
```

Can anyone let me know the mistake I am making?

I have now changed the make file as:

```
TARGET_BIN = \
       $(OBJDIR)/example-f.o

all : $(TARGET_BIN)

$(OBJDIR)/%: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
    -@$(MKDIRS) $(dir $@)
    @echo "here" $(dir $@)
    $(PVFMM_DIR)/libtool --mode=link --tag=FC mpif90 $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $^ $(LDLIBS) -c $@
```

And the example-f.f90 subroutine exists in src. When I tried to compile, I received the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/bidesh/Coding/FMM/pvfmm-develop/examples'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'obj/example-f.o', needed by 'all'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bidesh/Coding/FMM/pvfmm-develop/examples'
Makefile:1410: recipe for target 'all-examples' failed
make: *** [all-examples] Error 2
```

Maybe I am making some silly mistake. I am new to the Makefile and Linux environment. I will be helped to known the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because this:

```
example-f.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
```

is not a pattern rule.  A pattern rule must have a pattern (`%`) in the *target*.  The pattern in the prerequisite is optional, but the pattern in the target is mandatory.

That is just an explicit rule for building the target `example-f.o` which lists the literal file `src/%.f90` as a prerequisite, and that file doesn't exist and make doesn't know how to build it, which is what it tells you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I changed it as: TARGET_BIN = \
       $(OBJDIR)/example-f.o

all : $(TARGET_BIN)

$(OBJDIR)/%: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
 -@$(MKDIRS) $(dir $@)
 @echo "here" $(dir $@)
 $(PVFMM_DIR)/libtool --mode=link --tag=FC mpif90 $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $^ $(LDLIBS) -c $@

Comment: Still, it gives: make[1]: Entering directory '/home/bidesh/Coding/FMM/pvfmm-develop/examples'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'obj/example-f.o', needed by 'all'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bidesh/Coding/FMM/pvfmm-develop/examples'
Makefile:1410: recipe for target 'all-examples' failed
make: *** [all-examples] Error 2

Comment: Although the subroutine exists in example/src.

Comment: It can't be the way you describe.  I recommend invoking `make -d` to get make to print debugging output about what is happening.  Please be sure that the parent makefile uses the variable `$(MAKE)` to invoke the sub-make, not the literal command `make`.  The output will be very long so you might want to redirect it to a file, then search for where it wants to build the target `obj/example-f.o` and see why it decides that this pattern rule doesn't match.